# Is it right move a question to where the audience exists?

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

5 days ago I asked a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52380/live-updating-headers-from-form-input-with-react-js). I wanted to get a review on my code structure. My question has gotten 105 views, 3 up votes, and I have put a bounty of 50 points on it. Since then I have only gotten one answer and it did very little to answer my question. The problem, as I see it is, I am asking a question about a relatively new framework, and I don't think there is a community for it on CodeReview yet. I had to create the reactjs tag for the question, compared to the 309 tagged questions on SO. There are people on SO who can answer questions about React.js, but it doesn't seem like they use CodeReview, meaning I probably won't get a meaningful answer. In this case is it ok to ask my question on a more popular StackExchange site, where I know the proper community exists? Or if the proper exchange cannot produce and answer is it best to just ask the question somewhere not in the Stack network?

Comment: I'm sort of wondering what your expectations are here.  You said it yourself: it's a new framework.  Ultimately, your positive or negative experience with it is going to be largely based on how long you work with it, what problems arise as you work with it, and how you deal with those problems and evolve your practices as a result.  You seem  to think there's a "right way" to use the framework, and that someone here (or someone else on the Internet) will know what that is.  Generally speaking, there is no "right way."  There is only that way which best meets your requirements.

Comment: As you said yourself, some questions might not have a large enough community of experts.  Have you tried asking your question on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/reactjs), like the [ReactJS website suggests?](http://facebook.github.io/react/support.html)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I admit I haven't gone to them yet. I was planning on going to them before SO, but I first wanted to check here and see if there was a structured way to deal with small/nonexistent communities with the the StackExchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this question is not appropriate for SO.  Questions of the form, "what do you think of this code" or "how could this code be improved" are going to be Too Broad on SO.  SO is designed for *specific* programming problems.

Comment: On top of that, half the time someone posts that type of question, I see people trying to get it moved to Code Review (oh, the irony).